# Step by step C compilation result in segfault

Tags: c, linux, compilation, ld

I'm trying to understand C compilation

Given this simple C code in main.c:

```
int main() {
    int a;
    a = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

I performed the following operations:

```
cpp main.c main.i
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1 main.i -o main.s
as -o main.o main.s
ld -o main.exe main.o
```

When executing main.exe, I get a Segmentation Fault.

How can I get a good memory addressing in this example?

Comment: use your olatrm gcc

Comment: What happens if you rename your `main()`  function to `start()`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Replacing the C startup code is not trivial. With a function `_start()` the linker warning is gone, but the program segfaults after returning from `_start()`.

Comment: @Bodo what's indeed what I suspected would happen

Comment: @johnnnn - The _Segmentation Fault_ occurs when `main()` returns, because there's no return address on the stack. Normally, `main()` is called from C run time code. You get an impression what is done in the linking step by `gcc -v -o main.exe main.o`.

Answer (score 7):

When I try the sequence of commands from your question on an x86_64 Ubuntu 19.10 system, I get a warning from `ld`:

```
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000401000
```

This is an indication that something is wrong.

The error means that  the linker did not find a symbol `_start` and used a default address instead. When running your program it will try to execute code at this address which apparently is invalid.

An executable program compiled from C code doesn't contain only your code. The compiler instructs the linker to add C run-time library and startup code. The startup code is responsible for initialization and for calling your `main` function.

Run e.g.

```
gcc -v -o main.exe main.o
```

to see what other files get added to your program. On my system this shows a few files with names starting with `crt` which means "C runtime".

If you don't use `gcc` to link your program but use `ld` directly, you have to manually add all necessary object files in a similar way as the compiler would do automatically.